# Idiomatic way of choosing between types based on a compile-time condition

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

Given an unknown type `T`, I need something which picks another type `R` based on the size of `T`. If `T` is 8 bytes the type should be `pcg64` and if `T` is 1 to 4 bytes it should be `pcg32` and otherwise an error should be produced.

This is what I have:

```
template <size_t S>
struct pick_pcg_base {
    static_assert(S == 32 || S == 64, "no appropriate pcg for types of this size");
};

template<>
struct pick_pcg_base<32> {
    using type = pcg32;
};

template<>
struct pick_pcg_base<64> {
    using type = pcg64;
};

template <typename T>
struct pick_pcg : public pick_pcg_base<sizeof(T) == 8 ? 64 : (sizeof(T) <= 4 ? 32 : 0)> {};
```

You would use it like:

```
template <typename T>
void foo() {
   pick_pcg<T>::type rng;
   ...
}
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to do it in C++14 with less boilerplate?

Comment: You might be looking for [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional)

Comment: If an answer solved your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending @Igor Tandetniks' comment:

```
template<class T>
    struct pick_pcg 
{
    static constexpr size_t S = sizeof(T) == 8 ? 64 : (sizeof(T) <= 4 ? 32 : 0);
    static_assert(S == 32 || S == 64, "no appropriate pcg for types of this size");
    using type = std::conditional<S == 32, pcg32,pcg64>;
};

template<class T>
    using pick_pcg_t = typename pick_pcg<T>::type;
```

You can now use it like

```
template <typename T>
void foo() {
   pick_pcg_t<T> rng;
   ...
}
```